# Why does declaring a variable named values as an object returns type of function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have used `var values = {};` in a JavaScript file. However when I test my application on Firefox `typeof(values)` returns function instead of object. This can easily be tested within Firefox console window. As this variable has been used many times in my application; changing it's name may not be a feasible solution. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to force this variable name as an object?
2. What other variable names should i be concerned in order to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your assignment tries to change the read-only property `window.values` which is a function, a console utility.

You don't have such problem if you do it in an inner scope:

```
(function(){ var values = {}; console.log(typeof values) })()
```

The difference between Chrome and Firefox is that Chrome doesn't define this property as read-only.

Comment: You also don't have this problem in real code. It's a console-only thing.

Comment: @user890255 - `values` definitely **isn't** pre-defined in Firefox outside the console (I checked). If you think it is, look at other scripts you have loaded. My basic recommendation (don't use global variables) applies regardless.

Answer (score 1):

That's just an artifact of the Firefox console, it doesn't affect your real code. If you use `typeof values` in your actual script code, you'll see that it's `undefined` (or `object` if you create it as shown in your question).

Firefox's console provides `values` as a means of seeing the values of an object:

```
>> values({foo: "bar"})
-> Array [ "bar" ]
```

There are other functions available in the Firefox console; they're [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter).

Chrome / Chromium has a bunch of them as well (including `values`), [documented here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference).

> Is there a way to force this variable name as an object?

In real script code, not the console, there's no problem using `values`. However, I suggest avoiding creating globals, since the global namespace is **very** crowded.

> What other variable names should i be concerned in order to avoid this problem?

`name` and `title` are common ones people trip over. This is another reason not to use global variables. Instead, put your code in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    // Your code here
})();
```

Comment: Same in chrome, when printing `values` it shows `ƒ values(object) {[Command Line API]}`

Answer (score -1):

Because by doing so in firefox, you're trying to override/re-assign the global read-only window object **values** which type is *function*

```
window.values // its a function
```

Chrome however doesnt treat `values` as a read-only object

In order to make it works as you wish in Firefox, you need to place it inside a function

```
function test() {
  var values = {};
  console.log(typeof values); // typeof: object
}
```